# Show attached images in bigger resolution when we click on it

Tags: feature-request, images

Whenever someone take a screenshot from his screen and attach it to his question its really hard to read texts from attached image because it will automatically stretch to a specific size.

Is it possible when we click on attached image we see it in a bigger resolution in a new page?

Please look at this question:
[Example of an attached image that its hard to read its texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104250/gettting-require-js-script-error)

Comment: That OP should post his text in the question...then we don't have to read the text....

Comment: But sometimes you want to show your files structure, like the example I showed in my post.

Comment: You can describe that as well. I downvote questions that primarily consist of a screenshot... The only time I see benefit in them is if you need for example to clarify rendering issues with html/css that can't be reproduced with a jsfiddle, or bugs in image effects but beyond that...

Comment: Anyway, in the vanishingly rare case such would be a good idea, you can do it yourself: Just put a link around the image. (The only times I have yet made an image clickable on the SE-network, was a meta-question about a deleted question: Clicking led directly to the question...)

Comment: I still see no harm if we see attached images with a better quality when we click on it. Despite of this specific question, attached images can be very useful, you can describe trees structures and many other things with images which is very hard to describe with text.

Comment: "I still see no harm" - The harm is in posting images that do nothing to enhance the question that could not also be done in text. Posting unnecessary images is annoying for several reasons. 1) The images are often blocked by proxies, meaning that a lot of people can't see the content of the question. 2) Images typically don't scale well to mobile users, meaning they also can't see the majority of the content. 3) Mobile users often have data limits, and non-essential images cost them that data unnecessarily. Write your question instead of being lazy and posting images you don't need to post.

Comment: @KenWhite, In my opinion if a feature is harmful it shouldn't be implement, but if you implement it then its better to implement it in best way :)

Comment: On the rare occasions that I find posts that have images I want to see more clearly, I right-click the image in my browser and choose 'View Image`, and then use the web browser tab to zoom in. I'm not sure why that's not good enough, especially when images should be limited in use to those that are absolutely necessary.

Comment: @KenWhite well, thanks, I will get a try of it next time

Answer (score 7):

It goes without saying, any code or error messages in your question should obviously be entered using text. *However*:

- There's plenty of things that have varying levels of detail that could belong in a question that *aren't* code or text
- On sites that heavily discuss graphing, rendering and the like, this could be even more useful

*But*, the higher-resolution image would need to be available. That means it would have to be (by default) clear enough for anyone to get any needed detail.

Essentially, this just automates what folks sometimes do manually, which is upload the higher resolution to imgur, then insert the preview imgur generates into the post, and link the two together.

Not putting a status on this yet, the idea itself isn't at all bad, I just don't know how many people would find it of use, and retroactive usefulness depends on existing images being suitable when viewed at their source.

Comment: please don't as this will encourage people to post screenshots of their code rather than their actual SSCCE as code

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to make an image clickable by markup, for example an image included like:

`![enter image description here][1]`

can be changed with link markup to:

`[![enter image description here][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ1r2.jpg)`

thus giving a clickable image like:

[image]

A little cumbersome, and not so nice with the imgur reference, but at least there is a possibility until SO gets a build-in feature for clickable images.

Comment: No need to write the URL twice. `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`

Comment: But this means the user is now taken away from SO. User will expect to be able to click a close button or something on the full size image to go back to the page, but they can't. They can hit back button, but this is not very intuitive because it's not how "click on image to enlarge" works on most other websites.